# How do I maximize the sum of three absolute value functions?

Tags: optimization, absolute-value

Given the three absolute value functions:

f1 (x) = − |x − 1|, 
f2 (x) = − |x − 2|, 
f3 (x) = |x − 3|

How do I maximize the sum of these three functions?

Comment: Hint: Try drawing a graph

Comment: look at x < 1, 1 < x < 2, 2 < x < 3 and x > 3 separately - ineach case you will get a linear function which is easy to maximise

Comment: or since you know its a piecewise linear function, you can consider f(1), f(2), f(3) and the maximum of these will be the maximum on [1,3]

Comment: @Timnu4 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Direct method

- $x<1\implies \sum f=-(1-x)-(2-x)+(3-x)=x$
- $1\le x<2\implies \sum f=-(x-1)-(2-x)+(3-x)=-x+2$
- $2\le x<3\implies \sum f=-(x-1)-(x-2)+(3-x)=-3x+6$
- $x\ge3\implies \sum f=-(x-1)-(x-2)+(x-3)=-x$

[Plot of -|x-1|-|x-2|+|x-3|](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%7Cx-1%7C-%7Cx-2%7C%2B%7Cx-3%7C)

Answer (score 2):

First, let's look at $f_2 + f_3$.

[image: Just $f_2 + f_3$]

Clearly, the contributions of $f_2$ and $f_3$ cannot cause a maximum or minimum to be distinguishable on $(-\infty, 2]$ or on $[3,\infty]$.  Since the maximum of $f_1$ occurs at $1$, and this is in the interval for the maximum of $f_2 + f_3$, themaximum is at $x = 1$.

[image: The full objective function]

How else could we get this?

- The slope of $f_1$ is $1$ on $(-\infty,1)$ and $-1$ on $(1,\infty)$.
- The slope of $f_2$ is $1$ on $(-\infty,2)$ and $-1$ on $(2,\infty)$.
- The slope of $f_3$ is $-1$ on $(-\infty,3)$ and $1$ on $(3,\infty)$.

Consequently, the total slope is $1$ on $(-\infty,1)$, $-1$ on $(1,2)$, $-3$ on $(2,3)$, and $-1$ on $(3, \infty)$.  The only transition from rising to falling slopes is at $1$, so the objective function has a local maximum at $x=1$.  Since the value of the objective function only increases as $x$ increases to $1$ (from the left) and only decreases as $x$ increases from $1$ (to the right), $x = 1$ is the location of the global maximum.